# convert POST array to json format

Tags: php, json

How can I convert php's POST variable to json format?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If this is entirely in php, and you simply want to convert the data in `$_POST` to JSON, you can do so like this:

```
$json = json_encode($_POST);
```

Using php's built-in function `json_encode` ([doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php))

If this is not what you want to do, please be more specific with your question.

Comment: actually php POST -> array -> json

Comment: @downvoter kindly remove the downvote. My answer is correct, accepted and was first by a couple of seconds (sort by oldest to see for yourself)

Comment: When using the line above, is there something you can do about someone POSTing a gigantic piece of content, which could cause `json_encode` to perform poorly?  Is that a concern for anyone?

Answer (score 3):

```
json_encode($_POST);
```

- Docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php